Error parsing urdf file, two root links were found (link_1 and base_link)
heres my urdf file:
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<robot name="fanuc_crx10ial">

  <!-- Add a world link -->
  <link name="world"/>

  <!-- links: main serial chain -->
  <link name="base_link">
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://base_link.stl"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="">
        <color rgba="0.23921568627450981 0.23921568627450981 0.23921568627450981 1.0"/>
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://base_link.stl"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
   <inertial>
            <mass value="10" />
            <inertia ixx="0.00006" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="0.00007" iyz="0.0" izz="0.0001" />
        </inertial>
  </link>
  <link name="link_1">
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://link_1.stl"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="">
        <color rgba="0.86 0.85 0.81 1.0"/>
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://link_1.stl"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <inertial>
            <mass value="4" />
            <inertia ixx="0.00016" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="0.00012" iyz="0.000012" izz="0.00009" />
        </inertial>
  </link>
  <link name="link_2">
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://link_2.stl"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="">
        <color rgba="0.86 0.85 0.81 1.0"/>
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://link_2.stl"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
   <inertial>
            <mass value="8" />
            <inertia ixx="0.009" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="0.009" iyz="-0.00032" izz="0.0008" />
        </inertial>
  </link>
  <link name="link_3">
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://link_3.stl"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="">
        <color rgba="0.86 0.85 0.81 1.0"/>
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://link_3.stl"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
   <inertial>
            <mass value="4" />
            <inertia ixx="0.000028" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="0.00005" iyz="0.0" izz="0.00005" />
        </inertial>
  </link>
  <link name="link_4">
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://link_4.stl"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="">
        <color rgba="0.86 0.85 0.81 1.0"/>
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://link_4.stl"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
   <inertial>
            <mass value="5.5" />
            <inertia ixx="0.00004" ixy="0.000005" ixz="0.0" iyy="0.00035" iyz="0.0" izz="0.00035" />
        </inertial>
  </link>
  <link name="link_5">
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://link_5.stl"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="">
        <color rgba="0.86 0.85 0.81 1.0"/>
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://link_5.stl"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <inertial>
            <mass value="4" />
            <inertia ixx="0.000012" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="0.000016" iyz="0.0" izz="0.00002" />
        </inertial>
  </link>
  <link name="link_6">
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://link_6.stl"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="">
        <color rgba="0.23921568627450981 0.23921568627450981 0.23921568627450981 1.0"/>
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://link_6.stl"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <inertial>
            <mass value="2" />
            <inertia ixx="0.00" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="0.00" iyz="0.0" izz="0.00" />
        </inertial>
  </link>

<ros2_control name="controller_manager" type="system">
  <hardware>
    <plugin>fake_components/GenericSystem</plugin>
  </hardware>
  <!-- Create a fixed joint between world and base_link -->
  <joint name="world_to_base" type="fixed">
    <parent link="world"/>
    <child link="base_link"/>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
  </joint>
  <joint name="joint_1" type="revolute">
    <command_interface name="position">
    </command_interface>
    <state_interface name="position">
      <param name="initial_value">0.0</param> 
    </state_interface>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0.245"/>
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="link_1"/>
    <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
    <limit effort="0" lower="-3.141592653589793" upper="3.141592653589793" velocity="2.0943951023931953"/>
  </joint>

  <joint name="joint_2" type="revolute">
    <command_interface name="position">
    </command_interface>
    <state_interface name="position">
      <param name="initial_value">0.0</param> 
    </state_interface>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
    <parent link="link_1"/>
    <child link="link_2"/>
    <axis xyz="0 1 0"/>
    <limit effort="0" lower="-3.141592653589793" upper="3.141592653589793" velocity="2.0943951023931953"/>
  </joint>

  <joint name="joint_3" type="revolute">
    <command_interface name="position">
    </command_interface>
    <state_interface name="position">
      <param name="initial_value">0.0</param> 
    </state_interface>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0.710"/>
    <parent link="link_2"/>
    <child link="link_3"/>
    <axis xyz="0 -1 0"/>
    <limit effort="0" lower="-4.71238898038469" upper="4.71238898038469" velocity="3.141592653589793"/>
  </joint>

  <joint name="joint_4" type="revolute">
    <command_interface name="position">
    </command_interface>
    <state_interface name="position">
      <param name="initial_value">0.0</param> 
    </state_interface>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
    <parent link="link_3"/>
    <child link="link_4"/>
    <axis xyz="-1 0 0"/>
    <limit effort="0" lower="-3.3161255787892263" upper="3.3161255787892263" velocity="3.141592653589793"/>
  </joint>

  <joint name="joint_5" type="revolute">
    <command_interface name="position">
    </command_interface>
    <state_interface name="position">
      <param name="initial_value">0.0</param> 
    </state_interface>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.540 -0.150 0"/>
    <parent link="link_4"/>
    <child link="link_5"/>
    <axis xyz="0 -1 0"/>
    <limit effort="0" lower="-3.141592653589793" upper="3.141592653589793" velocity="3.141592653589793"/>
  </joint>

  <joint name="joint_6" type="revolute">
    <command_interface name="position">
    </command_interface>
    <state_interface name="position">
      <param name="initial_value">0.0</param> 
    </state_interface>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.160 0 0"/>
    <parent link="link_5"/>
    <child link="link_6"/>
    <axis xyz="-1 0 0"/>
    <limit effort="0" lower="-3.3161255787892263" upper="3.3161255787892263" velocity="3.141592653589793"/>
  </joint>
</ros2_control>
</robot>

when i test it with the check_urdf command I get the error two root links were found I dont understand why since all my links and joints seem to be defined correctly!
Thanks

Not sure this is the issue, but you seem to define the robot twice?

copy paste error my bad

I might be wrong but you seem to have two user accounts: (1 and 2). Please see I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?

I can't test this right now, but I think that everything that goes inside the <ros2_control>...</ros2_control> is only used by ros2_control. So I think you will need to define the joints (also?) outside of the ros2_control block.
